# Programming xillinx cpld xc9536xl

Tags: hardware, fpga, quartus

Iam trying to program xillinx cpld xc9536xl and I'm using quartus prime lite edition latest version and I don't know which device to select while downloading quartus to help me applying code on xillinx cpld
The devices are :
Arria || device support
Cyclone
Cyclone 10
Max ||
Max 10

Comment: Altera is the direct competitor of Xilinx, you cannot use their IDEs for non-Altera devices. You need to use Xilinx's ISE Design Suite.

Answer (score 0):

xc9536xl is a Xilinx part, not Intel/Altera.

Use the ISE 14.7 suite (free WebPACK edition) to program this part.

And it's likely you will need the Xilinx Platform Cable. ISE won't be using Intel USB Blaster, and I'm not familiar with open-source tools that could use Intel USB Blaster to program Xilinx parts.